# best way to write a python socket server 

Tags: python, sockets

i want to create a python socket server to  send and get data to html5 ,

what is the best way to do it , a python socket lib ? or a simple code  ?

thanks

Comment: What's wrong with the examples in the python [socket documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@srgerg's [socket documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#example) is useful, but if you want to handle multiple sockets simultaneously, you'll also need other mechanisms, such as [`select`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html), [`epoll`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#edge-and-level-trigger-polling-epoll-objects), or [`kqueue`](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#kqueue-objects) (depending upon your platform). (You could also spawn multiple processes using [`fork`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.fork), or threads if the python threading implementation meets your needs, but both these approaches have enough complications that I'm reluctant to suggest them.)

Another approach is to use [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/servers.html) to manage your networking via an event loop, similar to using [libevent](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/), but I always found Twisted documentation difficult to follow. Maybe you will have better luck than I did.